# How to create symlinks in laravel for a directory to a external link

Tags: php, linux, laravel, symlink, symlink-traversal

I want to create symlinks for my laravel site media link from

```
`/public/uploads/*` to a link `abc.com/public/uploads/*`
```

For example,
I have a site abc.com
There an image with media url :

```
abc.com/apple.jpg
```

And i have s3 spaces where 
My apple.jpg image is in

```
*digitalocoeanspaces.com/apple.jpg
```

So i want that

`abc.com/apple.jpg` should be fetched from spaces without link `*digitalocoeanspaces.com/apple.jpg`
So how can I do that

Comment: Sounds good - what's your question about this? How is this even related to PHP or Laravel?

Comment: I want to fetch an image from my domain say - abc.com/123.jpg  but the image 123.jpg should be fetch from external link from spaces that is xyz.com/123.jog.

Comment: Please add all explanation to your question by editing it. And are you sure about the term symlinking? Looks like you want to load assets from a completely different URL

Comment: I have edited check it out